# Composition: Should I access the "inner object's" methods directly?

Tags: python, oop

I am relatively new to OOP, and definitely still learning. I would like to know what is the best practice when dealing with two classes such as this:

*(I have reverse engineered the statistics engine of an old computer game, but I guess the subject does not matter to my question)*

```
class Step(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.input = 'G'

    ...more attributes...

    def reset_input(self):
        ''' Reset input to None. '''
        self.input = None
        print '* Input reset.'

        ... more methods ...
```

Then I have the Player class, which is the main object to control (at least in my design):

```
class Player(object):
    ''' Represents a player. Accepts initial stats.'''
    def __init__(self, step= 250, off= 13, dng= 50000, dist= 128, d_inc= 113):
        self.route = []
        self.step = Step(step=step, off=off, dng=dng, dist=dist, d_inc=d_inc)
        self.original = copy.copy(self.step)
```

As you can see, Player contains a Step object, which represents the next Step.

**I have found that I sometimes want to access a method from that Step class.
In this case, is it better to add a wrapper to Player, such as:**

(If I want to access `reset_input()`):

```
class Player(object):
    ...
    def reset_input(self):
        self.step.reset_input()
```

Then for Player to reset the input value:

```
p = Player()
p.reset_input()
```

**Or would it be better practice to access the `reset_input()` directly with:**

```
p = Player()
p.step.reset_input()
```

It seems adding the wrapper is just **duplicating** code. It's also annoying as I need access to quite a few of Step's methods.

So, when using composition (*I think it is the correct term*), is it good practice to directly access the 'inner' objects methods?

Comment: It's better for the `Player` object to reset the input value. The extra level of indirection will allow you to easily change how `Player` objects do things in the future. It's called information hiding or encapsulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should apply an additional layer of abstraction in OOP if:

1. you foresee yourself updating the code later; and
2. the code will be used in multiple places.

In this case, let's say you go with this method:

```
def reset_input(self):
    self.step.reset_input()
```

and then you call it in multiple places in your code. Later on, you decide that you want to do action `x()` before all your calls to `reset_input`, pass in optional parameter `y` to `reset_input`, and do action `z()` after that. Then it's trivial to update the method as follows:

```
def reset_input(self):
    self.x()
    self.step.reset_input(self.y)
    self.z()
```

And the code *will be changed everywhere* with just a few keystrokes. Imagine the nightmare you'd have on your hands if you had to update all the calls in multiple places because you weren't using a wrapper function.

You should apply a wrapper if you actually foresee yourself *using* the wrapper to apply changes to your code. This will make your code easier to maintain. As stated in the comments, this concept is known as **encapsulation**; it allows you to use an interface that hides implementation details, so that you can easily update the implementation at any time and it will change the code universally in a very simple way.

Answer (score 1):

It's always a tradeoff. Look at the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). It describes your situation and also pros and cons of different solutions.